# Focus Lab Config 403 Forbidden Error. Moving site from production to localhost

Tags: focus-lab-master-config, .htaccess

I'm very new to EE (coming from a Wordpress background). I'm trying to make changes to an existing site without editing the live site. So I'm trying move the live site to my localhost (I'm running LAMP).

Everything looks correct: Have a fresh dump of the database on my local machine, it's connected to the DB, All of the files look correct, etc. But for some reason I either get at 403 Forbidden error or a 500 Internal Server error.

I have a sneaky feeling that it's the Focus Lab .htaccess file that might be the culprit. Been googling and haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: The Focus Lab Master Config doesn't have an .htaccess included with it. It only impacts the config files, config.php and database.php

Comment: Try removing the htaccess file and see if that helps. If it doesn't then try putting removing the Master Config.

Comment: Where have you put the files on the server? The Focus Labs config is generally placed above the web root and often the system folder is placed above the web root too.

Comment: "I have a sneaky feeling that it's the Focus Lab .htaccess file that might be the culprit."

As the creator, I have a sneaky feeling you're using something in addition to the Master Config since it doesn't come with any .htaccess magic. :) Can you share you .htaccess contents in your description here?