# 403 error when moving a site from production to localhost

Tags: ee2

My question is very similar to [this one](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/24157).

I am new to Expression Engine and CMS in general. I'm trying to change an existing live site using EE2. So I copied all the files to my local machine (WAMP) and imported the database. I added config/config.local.php with my database credentials. When I try to access the site I get a 403 Forbidden error page saying:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at localhost Port 8080

I have tried removing the .htaccess file from the root, but I get the same error.

**What additional configuration do I have to add to move a site from production to localhost?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a config/config.local.php, I put my database credentials in the existing config.dev.php.